# Create Fuseki in memory server

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, fuseki

There is a parameter `--mem` in Fuseki:

```
fuseki-server --mem  /DatasetPathName
```

Could I use it to load full tdb indices into memory to improve query performance?

For example,

```
fuseki-server --mem  --loc=/tdbpath  /DatasetPathName
```

/tdbpath is a directory with tdb index and files (I load my data using tdbloader).

I tried it a little but found that the adding mem doesn't increase the usage of memory (comparing with fuseki-server --loc=/tdbpath  /DatasetPathName). Did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check [the Fuseki documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/)? It clearly says that "--mem
Create an empty, in-memory (non-persistent) dataset."  Generally in-memory stores will be faster than disk-based ones.  What exactly is the question?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks for the editing. I checked the document. Actually, my question is that: could I use this parameter to load the full tdb index into memory to get better performance? (e.g. fuseki-server --mem  --loc=/tdbpath  /DatasetPathName )

Comment: The dataset will be cached as it is used.  If you want to force them into memory, you can fire some queries at the server.  On 64 bit hardware, most data is cached outside the JVM heap. Without more details, it hard to say more.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of [`FusekiCmd#processModulesAndArgs()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-fuseki-core/2.3.0/org/apache/jena/fuseki/cmd/FusekiCmd.java#FusekiCmd.FusekiCmdInner.processModulesAndArgs%28%29), Fuseki interprets the arguments `--mem`, `--memtdb` and `--loc=X` as mutually exclusive specifications of the existence of a single dataset. Providing both `--mem` and `--loc=X` in the same set of command-line arguments results in only `--loc=X` being used:

```
        if ( contains(argMem) ) {
            log.info("Dataset: in-memory") ;
            cmdLineDataset = new ServerInitialConfig() ;
            cmdLineDataset.argTemplateFile = Template.templateMemFN ; 
        }

        if ( contains(argFile) ) {
            String filename = getValue(argFile) ;
            log.info("Dataset: in-memory: load file: " + filename) ;
            if ( !FileOps.exists(filename) )
                throw new CmdException("File not found: " + filename) ;

            // Directly populate the dataset.
            cmdLineDataset = new ServerInitialConfig() ;
            cmdLineDataset.dsg = DatasetGraphFactory.createMem() ;

            // INITIAL DATA.
            Lang language = RDFLanguages.filenameToLang(filename) ;
            if ( language == null )
                throw new CmdException("Can't guess language for file: " + filename) ;
            RDFDataMgr.read(cmdLineDataset.dsg, filename) ;
        }

        if ( contains(argMemTDB) ) {
            //log.info("TDB dataset: in-memory") ;
            cmdLineDataset = new ServerInitialConfig() ;
            cmdLineDataset.argTemplateFile = Template.templateTDBMemFN ;
            cmdLineDataset.params.put(Template.DIR, Names.memName) ;
        }

        if ( contains(argTDB) ) {
            cmdLineDataset = new ServerInitialConfig() ;
            cmdLineDataset.argTemplateFile = Template.templateTDBDirFN ;
            String dir = getValue(argTDB) ;
            cmdLineDataset.params.put(Template.DIR, dir) ;
        }
```

As seen above, if one of these options is selected, later options can overwrite the dataset supplied through command-line arguments. At most, one can be used. That being said, you *can* tell Fuseski to use an in-memory TDB dataset using the `--memtdb` option. As per the documentation, this should only be used for testing.

As per [@andys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys), TDB (using the `--loc` option) should cache values into memory as they are used. If you need persistence and don't want to introduce additional lifecycle stages to your application, TDB is the best way to go. If your dataset can fit entirely in memory, you don't need persistence, or you can afford to introduce a separate save-and-shutdown step to your application, in-memory can be much much faster.